# Is there a way to have data copy and pasted from one table to another without having previous pasted data overwritten?

Tags: vba

So I want to copy data from one table to another. the first table will contain values accumulated over one month.at the end of the month, all of those values will be copied and pasted to another table that will store all data from every month. the issue that im running into is that when I run the macro to copy and paste the current months values to the 2nd table, the data already in the 2nd table gets overwritten. I somehow need the values already in the 2nd table to stay while the new data is pasted above the old values, therefore the table would expand. Thanks!

```vbs
Public Sub CopyMonthBudget()
    
    Worksheets(3).Range("Budget.Log").Copy Worksheets(4).Range("A" & Worksheets(4).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
    Worksheets(3).Range("Budget.Log").ClearContents
    Worksheets(3).ListObjects("Budget.Log").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `paste`, use `insert copied cells`.  A popup will appear and ask whether you want to have the displaced cells moved down or to the right.

FYI, the shortcut entries after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> are <kbd>Context Menu</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>; the copied cells need to have copy focus (dotted lines around copied cells) for `insert copied cells` to appear in context menu.  You can also copy entire rows or columns, and inserting will automatically push the rows/columns down/over respectively.